# I was lucky to get a job out of nowhere, it is killing me now, what should I do now?

Tags: professionalism, communication, career-development, resignation, work-experience

I was working in a high-tech company after my PhD and randomly one day one of my suppliers called me and asked me if I wanted to join them. By that time was fed up with my job.

The supplier company was a small but well-established embedded system development company. No interviews, no CVs we had a friendly chat, and he asked how much want etc. After consulting a few people and considering my previous company situation (financial) I decided to accept his offer.

I was very lucky my previous company collapsed after I joined the new place. It is a small company with less than 10 employees, and they all are well-seasoned and experienced people. They offered a good salary too. If I compare myself to them I probably knew 1% of their skills. I asked him why he trust me, he said that "I don't care about your skills and they can be developed, but the important thing for me is an attitude". I directly dealt with them for more than 3 years as my supplier.

But now he wanted me to do an embedded system project which is based on low-level C programming. I have done programming using C++, Python, etc, but not low-level C. And the stuff I have to do is absolutely abstract to me. He is very kind to me these days, sits with me try to teach me stuff. But without having solid background stuff, I have to do in advanced C.

I am not a natural programmer, I never wanted to do programming as a professional thing, but I like building embedded systems etc and I have done a lot of cool stuff. Also I am willing to learn for the Job, but he wants it done fast.

I am spending hours on the internet trying to understand coding stuff! Feels like I am wasting time. I have stressed out now. Every day I started to develop a nagging feeling about it. I know he kept faith in me, but for how long?

I am lost now, what should I do? Do I resign from the job, or keep going?

Comment: I'd say, you have got a very good and supportive employer - try to live up to their trust in you - focus on learning and at the same time, start contributing.

Comment: C is minimalistic but C++ is just C with added stuff. The major thing new developers have to learn with C is the manual memory management, but c++ teaches you that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This *is* almost all about attitude. If you believe you can learn, you can learn. If management hired you knowing that you need to learn, they have allowed for the needed time. If the manager still has faith in you, I'd trust that intuition and not panic yet. Everyone starts as a student, and it does take time to learn this stuff.

Consider looking for a real class rather than internet scraps -- either on the net, or live. Having a real structured curriculum with graded homework *is* significantly easier for most folks.

Once you start to develop some skill, start reading the department's existing code and work on understanding how that works and why its authors made those choices.

Yes, this is going to be challenging. It's up to you to decide whether being paid to tackle that challenge is fun and a good investment in your future, something you hate doing and want to stop doing, or somewhere between the two. Personally, I'd say you have a great opportunity to learn something valuable and (for many, though not all) fun, and for now you should just focus on doing so.

If management isn't saying they are concerned, don't borrow trouble. Relax and focus on studying until they say otherwise.

Or, if you really, really, REALLY can't -- if you're outright failing the structured course and can't get help fixing that -- talk to management about whether they and you might have made a mistake. Note that "and". They took a gamble on you and trusted that your attitude -- your enthusiasm and determination -- would be what made the difference. They *could* have been wrong. But wouldn't it be more fun to put in the work needed to prove them right?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, ask yourself what you want to do in long term. If you think the path you're taking is aligned with your long term roadmap and career vision, then I'd say you're in good hands - you have an employer who wants you to succeed and is willing to provide the support you need. You should make use of the opportunity to learn and grow.

However, since time is of essence, do not wait till you "master" something - you start applying the knowledge and start showing the outcome, no matter how small it is. Maybe you can review something which was already built, contribute to a small part of a work being managed / handled by someone else, etc etc. That way, you can show you are learning and growing, giving confidence to your employer, and also assuring them to invest more time and effort to keep training you.

However, if you feel this is not something that you want to do, then you need to make it very clear to them, and either they provide you with some other responsibility (seems unlikely by seeing the org size, but no harm in asking), or you need to find another opportunity which is aligned with your goals.